# jQuery on click gets the same data attribute value every time

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have the following code:

```
$('body').on('click','#confirm_remove',function(){
  alert($(this).data('whattoremove'));
});
```

The `#confirm_remove` is a button id inside a bootstrap modal, who's data attribute (whattoremove) gets updated every time the modal opens - this is verified, but for some reason the data in the jQuery function has the same value on every click - this is the value of the first time it was clicked.

Any ideas on how to fix this.

Comment: Please share you `HTML` code.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('#confirm_remove').click(function(){
  alert( $('#confirm_remove').attr('whattoremove') );
});
```

Comment: While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.